# Which design pattern to be used for handling multiple input & multiple output?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am trying to come up with a low-level design on how to handle multiple inputs and multiple outputs. Specifically, with regard to Amazon Alexa.

Alexa can take multiple inputs -> Voice/Text.
Alexa can put out multiple outputs -> Voice/Text/Email, etc.

What design pattern would you use?

Comment: Accurately answering your question is impossible due to the fact that you want a low-level solution (I assume an implementation in some programming language) but state the problem in a high-level fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide message conversion and message processing to separate component, because they are two different problems. With conversion you can use polymorphism so it's easy to add new formats. So it would go something like this:

```
class Alexa {
    fun process(input: AlexaInput): AlexaOutput
}


class AlexaInput(
    //.. whatever raw data Alexa input consists of (regardless of the format it came as)
)

class AlexaOutput(
    //.. whatever raw data Alexa output consists of (regardless of the format it came as)
)

interface AlexaInputConverter<T> {
    fun convert(input: T): AlexaInput
    fun supports(inputMessageType: InputMessageType): Boolean
}

interface AlexaOutputConverter<T> {
    fun convert(output: AlexaOutput): T
    fun supports(outputMessateType: OutputMessageType): Boolean
}

class AlexaVoiceInputConverter: AlexaInputConverter<VoiceMessage> {
    override fun convert(input: VoiceMessage): AlexaInput {
        // ... implementation of voice to AlexaInput
    }

    override fun supports(inputMessageType: InputMessageType): Boolean {
        return inputMessageType == VOICE;
    }
}

class AlexaTextInputConverter: AlexaInputConverter<TextMessage> {
    override fun convert(output: AlexaOutput): TextMessage {
        // ... implementation of output to text
    }

    override fun supports(inputMessageType: InputMessageType): Boolean {
        return inputMessageType == TEXT;
    }
}

class AlexaVoiceOutputConverter: AlexaOutputConverter<VoiceMessage> {
    override fun convert(output: AlexaOutput): VoiceMessage {
        // ... implementation of raw data to Voice Message
    }

    override fun supports(outputMessateType: OutputMessateType): Boolean {
        return outputMessateType == VOICE;
    }
}

class AlexaTextOutputConverter: AlexaOutputConverter<TextMessage> {
    override fun convert(output: AlexaOutput): TextMessate {
        // ... implementation of raw data to Text Message
    }

    override fun supports(outputMessateType: OutputMessateType): Boolean {
        return outputMessateType == TEXT;
    }
}


fun main() {

    val inputConverters = getInputConverters()
    val outputConverters = getOutputConverters()
    val inputMessage = getInputMessage()
    val inputData = inputConverters.first { it.supports(inputMessage.type) }.convert(inputMessage)
    val outputData = alexa.process(inputData)
    val outputFormat = getPreferredOutputFormat()
    val outputMessage = outputConverters.first { it.supports == outputFormat }.convert(outputData)
    // do something with the output message...
}
```

I used Kotlin here as the language of choice, but you can implement similar pattern in most of the languages.
In addition to extendability, this kind of structure is very easy to write unit tests on.